# Codeigniter - Only allow to edit or delete when status is still created

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to disable button edit and delete when status is declined or approved? So the user only can edit Item Requisiton only when status is still Sent for approval.

[image: screen]

This is my **view** :

```
<tbody>
          <?php 
            $counter=1+intval($this->uri->segment(3));
            foreach($requisition_list as $l){ 
          ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control grey" name="ID_REQUISITION[]" value="<?= $l->ID_REQUISITION ?>"></label>
              </td>
              <td><?= $counter ?></td>
              <td><?= $l->KD_REQUISITION ?></td>
              <td><?= $l->STATUS_NAME ?></td>
              <td class="center">
                <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <a href="<?= base_url('item_requisition/edit').'?id='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-mini tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-confirm-modal="<?= base_url('item_requisition/delete').'?ID_REQUISITION='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php 
            $counter++;
            }
          ?>
        </tbody>
```

**Controller** :

```
$perpage = 20;
$params = array(0, 0, 0);
$pagination = array(
    'base_url' => base_url("item_requisition/index"),
    'total_rows' => sizeof($this->call_sp("view_item_requisition", $params)),
    'per_page' => $perpage,
    'num_links' => 3,
    'uri_segment' => 3
);
$params = array($perpage, $offset, 0);

$this->data['requisition_list'] = $this->call_sp("view_item_requisition", $params);
$this->data['pagination'] = $this->paging($pagination);
$this->render($this->data, "index");
```

Comment: before the html code that does not need to be displayed when the status is  declined or approved add: <?php if ($l->STATUS_NAME == 'declined' || $l->STATUS_NAME == 'approved'): ?> after add <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can creat a `$_SESSION['aprouved']` and à database value like approuved in user table. It's dépende what you realy want. Use this session configuration too make sur it's safe.

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
ini_set('session.use_cookie', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookie', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookie', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to hide the buttons, or disable them. When you decide to disable them apply validation on your controller

```html
<tbody>
  <?php 
    $counter=1+intval($this->uri->segment(3));
    foreach($requisition_list as $l){ 
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control grey" name="ID_REQUISITION[]" value="<?= $l->ID_REQUISITION ?>"></label>
      </td>
      <td><?= $counter ?></td>
      <td><?= $l->KD_REQUISITION ?></td>
      <td><?= $l->STATUS_NAME ?></td>      
      <td class="center">
      <?php

       if ($l->STATUS_NAME == 'declined' || $l->STATUS_NAME == 'approved') {
         $disabled = 'disabled="disabled"'
       }
       
      ?>
        <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <a href="<?= base_url('item_requisition/edit').'?id='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-mini tooltips" <?php  echo $disabled; ?> data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-confirm-modal="<?= base_url('item_requisition/delete').'?ID_REQUISITION='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" <?php  echo $disabled; ?> class="btn btn-danger btn-mini tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php 
    $counter++;
    }
  ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: disable wont prevent changing the code in developer tools and still clicking on it...

Answer (score 0):

If they are never going to be available in those statuses just remove them from even being generated...

```
<tbody>
          <?php 
            $counter=1+intval($this->uri->segment(3));
            foreach($requisition_list as $l){ 
          ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control grey" name="ID_REQUISITION[]" value="<?= $l->ID_REQUISITION ?>"></label>
              </td>
              <td><?= $counter ?></td>
              <td><?= $l->KD_REQUISITION ?></td>
              <td><?= $l->STATUS_NAME ?></td>
              <td class="center">
                <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <php if ($l->STATUS_NAME == 'declined' || $l->STATUS_NAME == 'approved'): ?>
                    <a href="<?= base_url('item_requisition/edit').'?id='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-mini tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-confirm-modal="<?= base_url('item_requisition/delete').'?ID_REQUISITION='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                <?php endif;>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php 
            $counter++;
            }
          ?>
        </tbody>
```

Leaving the divs there shouldn't mess with your styling, but play with that to see if its actually needed to be there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the answer. I use this code for my condition :

```
<tbody>
          <?php 
            $counter=1+intval($this->uri->segment(3));
            foreach($requisition_list as $l){ 
          ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control grey" name="ID_REQUISITION[]" value="<?= $l->ID_REQUISITION ?>"></label>
              </td>
              <td><?= $counter ?></td>
              <td><?= $l->KD_REQUISITION ?></td>
              <td><?= $l->NAMA_UNIT ?></td>
              <td><?= $l->STATUS_NAME ?></td>
              <td class="center">
                <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <?php if ($l->STATUS_NAME == 'Sent for Approval'): ?>
                    <a href="<?= base_url('item_requisition/edit').'?id='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-mini tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-confirm-modal="<?= base_url('item_requisition/delete').'?ID_REQUISITION='.$l->ID_REQUISITION ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                <?php endif;?>
                </div>

              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php 
            $counter++;
            }
          ?>
        </tbody>
```

Although user still can edit by the id, at least i just need to make condition in my controller for approved/declined status is not editable.